# Multi-threading In Python to open more than thousand of urls and processing them faster

Tags: python, multithreading

I have wrote a python script to open arround 1k urls and process them to get the desired result,but it seems like eventhough multithreading has been introduced its working slowly, and after some urls have been processed,the process seems to be hanged, I am not able to decide whether its still running or stopped.How can I create multiple threads to process them faster.Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks in Advance. Below is my script.

```
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import 
DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as 
RemoteWebDriver
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # This is a thread-based Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import csv

def fetch_url(url):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    print(html)
    print("'%s\' fetched in %ss" % (url[0], (time.time() - start)))

def thread_task(lock,data_set):
    lock.acquire()
    fetch_url(url)
    lock.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_set = []
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for row in spamreader:
            data_set.append(row)

    lock = threading.Lock()
    # data set will contain a list of 1k urls
    for url in data_set:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_task, args=(lock,url,))
        # start threads
        t1.start()

        # wait until threads finish their job
        t1.join()

    print("Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start))
```

Comment: You're using a single lock for all your processing. Why are you using a lock at all?

Comment: I might recommend using requests_futures that currently does this

Comment: Hi Alex,My system was getting slow while running multiple threads as we can see here its creating one thread for each url for that reason I added lock.Let me know I I need to do any changes.

Comment: Hi Shailyn, I have no Idea on requests_futures can you let me know more on this with some examples.

Answer (score 2):

You've defeated multithreading first by waiting for each thread to finish in the `for url in data_set:` loop before starting the next, and then by using a lock to only let one instance of the the `fetch_url` function run at a time. You've imported `ThreadPool`, its a reasonable tool for the job. Here is how you could use it

```
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
import csv

def fetch_url(url):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    print(html)
    print("'%s\' fetched in %ss" % (url[0], (time.time() - start)))

def thread_task(lock,data_set):
    lock.acquire()
    fetch_url(url)
    lock.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        dataset = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|'))

    # guess a thread pool size which is a tradeoff of number of cpu cores,
    # expected wait time for i/o and memory size.

    with ThreadPool(20) as pool:
        pool.map(fetch_url, dataset, chunksize=1)

    print("Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start))
```

Comment: Hi Tdelaney, thank for your help and sugestion, I will try this code, also can you please help me in understanding this, ThreadPool(20) what it will do actually, suppose I have a data set of 1000 urls, how many thread will it create as per data set.

Comment: It creates 20 threads and `chunksize` tells it to pass urls to each worker one at a time as it completes the previous one. Scrapers spend a lot of time waiting for web sites to respond so if the actual scraping is fast, you can have more (waiting) workers than cpu cores available. Its more complicated to make a system that dynamically adjusts load - a thread pool is a quick and dirty way to get it done.

Comment: So it means 20 urls will be assigned to 20 threads and once its done again it will assign the next 20 and so on..?

Comment: Mostly... 1 url will be assigned to each of the 20 threads, so 20 will be in progress. As each thread finishes, it grabs the next url so all 20 threads will always be working. Doing it in groups of 20 would be bad since idle threads would have to wait for the slowest thread to finish.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have understood it now, so what will be the best practice to do it, pls suggest me, as for now I am running the script provided by you and I found its faster now while comparing to my script which I was running earlier.

Comment: You can look at cpu/memory/network/disk monitors to see if you are using your machine fully and adjust the number. If this is a long term program, there are many ways to do load balancing over a cluster of computers... but that's far beyond what we can suggest here on stackoverflow.